# How to Authorize Ajax request and validate JWT token is valid ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

This is my ajax code where i am send request to recevice data.

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    url: "/api/Values/endpoint",
                    data: data,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    //headers: { "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + window.sessionStorage.getItem("token") },
                    beforeSend: function (request) {
                            var token = window.sessionStorage.getItem("token");
                            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
                                "Bearer " + token);
                        },
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response != null) {
                            //my code here
                        } else {
                            alert("Something went wrong");
                        }
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("fail");
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert("error");
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

Here is my asp.net controller code it is receiving request even with authorize  with or without token it is giving me data back.

```
using Myproject.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;
using HttpGetAttribute = System.Web.Mvc.HttpGetAttribute;
using HttpPostAttribute = System.Web.Mvc.HttpPostAttribute;
using RouteAttribute = System.Web.Mvc.RouteAttribute;
using RoutePrefixAttribute = System.Web.Mvc.RoutePrefixAttribute;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Net.Mail;
using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities;
using System.Configuration;
using AuthorizeAttribute = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute;


namespace Myproject.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("api/Values")]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
    
         [HttpGet]
         //[System.Web.Http.Authorize]
         [Route("endpoint")]
         public async Task<IHttpActionResult> endpoint()
         {

         }    
    }
}
```

Here is my Startup.cs file.

```
using Microsoft.Owin; 
using Owin;
using System.Configuration;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Myproject.Startup))]

namespace Myproject
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions { });
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

What I can do to receive the token and validate the token and accordingly send back response.